# Dagre / D3 Rendering Nodes and Edges/Arrowheads at a larger size

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg, dagre-d3

I have this graph but it appears that the nodes and edges/arrowheads are rendering kind of small. The graph is being rendered using Dagre. I'm just wondering if there is a way to make the nodes and edges/arrowheads larger but keep them within the svg..is that possible? Or what would be causing these things to look smaller? Or is this normal functionality?

[image]

Here as well: is it possible to increase the size of the nodes and edges but keep it fit within the svg as it currently is?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the `stroke-width` on the edge

```
g.setEdge("A", "B", {
  style: "stroke: #f66; stroke-width: 3px; stroke-dasharray: 5, 5;",
  arrowheadStyle: "fill: #f66"
});
```

http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/style-attrs.html